# Prove that one element is bigger than or equal to the other.

Tags: proof-verification

I have the following two relations:

```
2^x =< (x+2)!
```

and

```
2^(x+1) =< (x+3)!
```

I assumed that the first statement is true and now, I'm trying to prove that the second statement is true too. I understand that I will have to substitute the first relation in the second and I attemted this multiple times, but I don't reach a relation that will prove it. Thanks

Comment: If you have proven $2^x \le (x+2)!$ then replace $x$ with $[x+1]$ and the second result immediately follows.  $2^{[x+1]} \le ([x+1] + 2)!$..

Comment: Oh, you assumed it was true and you are trying to do a proof by induction.... I see.  Okay.  $2^{x+1} = 2*2^x \le 2*(x+2)! < 3*(x+2)! \le (x+3)(x+2)! = (x+3)!$.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a proof involving induction over the natural numbers, so I will simply walk through the proof.

$\underline{\text{Proposition}}:$ For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is the case that $2^n \leq (n+2)!$

$\underline{\text{Proof}}:$ For our base case, notice that if $n = 0$ that $2^0 = 1 < 2 = 2! = (0 + 2)!$.

Now for our inductive step assume for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that $2^k = (k+2)!$ (our inductive hypothesis), and we may then see that
\begin{align*}
2^{k+1} &= 2 (2^k) \\
&\leq (k+3) 2^k \text{ (as }k + 2 \geq 2 \text{ for all natural numbers } k \text{)}\\
&\leq (k+3)((k+2)!) \text{ (by our inductive hypothesis)} \\
&= (k+3)! \\
\end{align*}
Thus we know that $2^{k+1} \leq ((k+1)+2)!$ as desired.

Therefore, by mathematical induction we have shown that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $2^n \leq (n+2)!$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is a non-negative integer and $2^x \leq (x + 2)!$

\begin{align*}
(x + 3)! &= (x + 3) (x + 2)! \\
&\geq 2 (x + 2)! \\
&\geq \ldots
\end{align*}